# .pfx File Preventing the Project From Compiling

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I inherited an old VS 2008 project which I was able to convert to VS 2012. The only issue I am running into is that when I run the project in 2008 or 2012, I receive the below error:

```
Error   1   Cannot import the following key file: . The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or import the certificate manually into the current user’s personal certificate store. DiagnosticTool.Presentation
```

Is there a way for me to exclude this key from the project? I have a very limited knowledge of PFX keys.

Comment: Do you know anything else about the certificate?

Comment: Nope. I scoured the documentation that the last developer left and there is no reference as to why this key is needed.

Comment: But do you know the purpose of the certificate?

Comment: Not within the project specifically but I am assuming it has something to do with release signing.

Comment: **SOLVED**  I was able to go into the project properties and remove the security options that were requiring the keys in question.

Comment: I had a feeling it was something like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842481/problem-with-temporarykey-pfx-i-dont-have-the-password That Link did fix this for me....